# Access folder$ from boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, winapi, boost

I have a folder named \Server\video which I can parse just fine using boost::filesystem, but the folder \Server\video$ I cannot.

The code I use was:

```
void find_files(const boost::filesystem::path& dir_path, std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>& results) {
    const boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end;
    boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator it;
    boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator current(dir_path);
    do {
        it = std::find_if(current, end,
            [](const boost::filesystem::directory_entry& e) {
            printf("%s\n", e.path().string().c_str());
            return e.path().extension() == ".avi" || e.path().extension() == ".mkv";
        });
        if (it != end) {
            results.push_back(it->path());
            current++;
        }
    } while (it != end);
}

int main(...) {

    boost::filesystem::path folder(L"\\\\Server\\video");
    boost::filesystem::path folderHidden(L"\\\\Server\\video$");

    std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> foundVideos;
    find_files(folderHidden, foundVideos);
    find_files(folder, foundVideos);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works great for the \video path, but fails completely, on the first entry, for video$. Is there any way for a quick fix on this?

Edit:
I added a printf() on e.path().string() to see where it fails:

```
\\Server\video$\$RECYCLE.BIN
\\Server\video$\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1894720951-1562977780-1489575960-5
00
```

The precise error message is

```
BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(filesystem_error(
            "filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator directory error",
            ec_push_directory));
```

in the operations.hpp

Comment: Please define "fails" precisely. In what manner does your code fail.

Comment: Unhandled exception: boost::filesystem::filesystem_error. The folder definitely exists though.

Comment: What is the actual error message carried in the exception? Update your code adding try-catch.

Comment: Please put all of this important information in the question

Comment: Oh, just noticed, it fails in the $Recycle.bin, not in the folder itself.

Comment: Your code confuses `find_file` with `find_files`. Making the example correct is a good idea.

Comment: When I manually use all subfolders I have in video$, it works, so it actually has something to do with the recycle bin.